# Finding points with matching slopes

Tags: java, points

Say I have a point (0,0) that I say will be used as the origin. How can I check that the following Points, (in an array) share the same slope based with respect to the origin.

The points are:

```
(6000, 7000) (10000, 0) (16000, 17000) (7000, 3000) 
(3000, 7000) (20000, 21000) (3000, 4000) (0, 10000).
```

Basically I want to compare each of the points with respect to the origin and see which ones share the same slope and group those points together in separate lists. I'm just a little confused on the algorithm and logic behind it. I know a for loop would be best but its implementation seems to be getting away from me

```
   for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; i++)
```

and here is where I start to lose my mind.

Comment: Would it not just be the division of the two?

slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

Comment: Simplest way: use a map of lists with the slopes as keys (Map<Double, List<Point>>) to collect the points with the same slopes (see other comment on how to calculate it). A better solution would take into account the imprecision of floating point operations, but you can probably ignore that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you've described is correct.  You want to "see which ones share the same slope and group those points together in separate lists".

You can use a `Map` to handle the grouping for you, like:

```
Map<BigDecimal, List<Point>> lists = new HashMap<BigDecimal, List<Point>>();
for (Point point : points) {
    BigDecimal slope = new BigDecimal(point.getY()).divide(new BigDecimal(point.getX()));
    List<Point> list = lists.get(slope);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<Point>();
        lists.put(slope, list);
    }
    list.add(point);
}
```

Note that this uses the arbitrary-precision `BigDecimal` class to avoid issues related to rounding of primitive floating-point types.  If you're not concerned about this, you could just use `Double` and `double` instead.

Comment: Is there any way I could accomplish the same thing but by just using a for loop and comparing each point's slope with respect to the origin using a side by side comparison? I'm not too advanced in my java skills as of yet, unfortunately.

Comment: @user1710357 - you could, but it would be less efficient.  You'd need to use two `for` loops, so that for each point you could check every other point to see if it has the same slope.  And you'd still need to collect your results somewhere, anyways.

Comment: Can you show me how it would go using the two for loops? I really appreciate the help you've given me so far!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of points, iterate the list, compute the slope and maintain the list of points against each computed slope in a map as below:

```
        List<int[]> myPoints = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        int[] point1 = new int[]{6000, 7000};
        myPoints.add(point1);
        int[] point2 = new int[]{10000, 0};
        myPoints.add(point2);
        int[] point3 = new int[]{16000, 17000};
        myPoints.add(point3);

        Map<Float, List<int[]>> myMatchingSlopePoints = new HashMap<Float, List<int[]>>();
        for(int[] point: myPoints){
            Float slope = new Float(point[1]/point[0]);
            if(myMatchingSlopePoints.get(slope) == null){
                //create a new list as this slope doesn't match with previous one
                myMatchingSlopePoints.put(slope, new ArrayList<int[]>());
            }
            //add the slope to match list
            myMatchingSlopePoints.get(slope).add(point);
        }

        //retrieve various slope
        Set<Float> variousFloats = myMatchingSlopePoints.keySet();

        //retrieve mathing points for each slope
        for(Float slope: variousFloats){
            List<int[]> matchingPointsListForSlope = myMatchingSlopePoints.get(slope);
            //use matching points
        }
```